# Group rows by similar name in column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

For calculations, I've already created this dataframe

df1:

```
+--------------+------+------------+
|name          |MG    |questions   |
+--------------+------+------------+
|toto          |MG1   |[Q1, Q2]    |
|toto          |MG3   |[Q4, Q6, Q7]|
|toto-123      |MG1   |[Q1, Q2]    |
|toto-456      |MG1   |[Q1, Q2]    |
|titi          |MG1   |[Q1, Q2]    |
|...           |...   |...         |
+--------------+------+------------+
```

Until now, it was enough, but now, for a new need, I encountered a problem I do not achieve to resolve: I have to group rows by `name` and `MG` not with the exact `name`, but with similar `name`, like that

df1:

```
+--------------+------+-----------------------------+
|name          |MG    |questions                    |
+--------------+------+-----------------------------+
|toto          |MG1   |[Q1, Q2] [Q1, Q2] [Q1, Q2]   |
|toto          |MG3   |[Q4, Q6, Q7]                 |
|titi          |MG1   |[Q1, Q2]                     |
|...           |...   |...                          |
+--------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Here, `questions` for toto are questions for `toto, toto-123 and toto-456`. They can stay in different arrays or in the same. Also ideally the rows for `toto-123` and `toto-456` still remain.

I've tried the `groupby` function with condition thought SQL expression but without success

Do you have any hint or solution?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you put a sample of what you start with and what you want as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first, use self join to find rows that have similar `name` and `mg` values, using `like` operator in join condition:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("toto", "MG1", ["Q1", "Q2"]), ("toto", "MG3", ["Q4", "Q6", "Q7"]),
    ("toto-123", "MG1", ["Q1", "Q2"]), ("toto-456", "MG1", ["Q1", "Q2"]),
    ("titi", "MG1", ["Q1", "Q2"])], ["name", "mg", "questions"])

similar_df = df.alias("a").join(
    df.alias("b"),
    F.expr("a.name like concat('%', b.name, '%') and a.mg = b.mg and a.name != b.name"),
).selectExpr("a.name", "a.mg", "b.name as similar_name")

similar_df.show()
#+--------+---+------------+
#|    name| mg|similar_name|
#+--------+---+------------+
#|toto-123|MG1|        toto|
#|toto-456|MG1|        toto|
#+--------+---+------------+
```

Then, join again with original dataframe and change the values of corresponding names with the similar one found in the first step, and finally group by `name` and `mg` to collect list of `questions`:

```
result = df.alias("df").join(
    similar_df.alias("s"),
    ["name", "mg"],
    'left'
).select(
    F.coalesce(F.col("similar_name"), F.col("df.name")).alias("name"),
    F.col("mg"),
    F.col("df.questions"),
).groupBy("name", "mg").agg(
    F.collect_list("questions").alias("questions")
)

result.show(truncate=False)
#+----+---+------------------------------+
#|name|mg |questions                     |
#+----+---+------------------------------+
#|toto|MG1|[[Q1, Q2], [Q1, Q2], [Q1, Q2]]|
#|titi|MG1|[[Q1, Q2]]                    |
#|toto|MG3|[[Q4, Q6, Q7]]                |
#+----+---+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @blackbishop, I had difficulties to adapt your solution to my project, but it works. And I finally use https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-flatten-nested-array-column-to-single-column/ to broke the array. Pyspark is really not obvious